# VBScript Compile Error

Tags: vbscript, compilation, shutdown

I've been making a script for school, but I've encountered a few problems...
This if my script ">" shows the error.
Complete error:
Line: 26
Char: 14
Error: Syntax Error

```
' Macro starter script -- basically for any teachers or students to understand and or improve my script.

'oShell.AppActivate("Paint"); // Set focus to a program
'WScript.Sleep(500);          // Delay for 1/2 second

'oShell.Run("notepad c:\\temp\\somefile.txt", 1, false);   // launch a program
'----------------------------- can add ,2 to run minimized, true=wait for exit

'oShell.SendKeys("%F");       // Alt+F  ----- SendKeys strings to jog my memory
'oShell.SendKeys("^C");       // Ctrl+C
'oShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");  // Send Enter key (also tilde {~} )
'oShell.SendKeys("{{TAB} 2"); // Send Tab key twice )
'oShell.SendKeys(" ");        // Send a space

'var nResult= oShell.Popup("Do you want to continue?", 0, "My Macro", 4+32 );
'if ( nResult==6 ) { // 6=Yes, 7=No, 
'   WScript.Echo( "you said 'Yes!'" );  
'}
'WScript.Echo( "done!" );

'Script Starts Here

var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo( "Script made by Joshua Hughes" )
var sResult = oShell.Popup("Do you want to save all work and shut down?", 0, "Shutdown", 4+32)

>if ( sResult==6 ) {

    WScript.Echo( "Starting, do not press any buttons or click!" )
    oShell.AppActivate("Word");
    WScript.Sleep(500);
    oShell.SendKeys("^S");
    oShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
    WScript.Sleep(500);
    oShell.SendKeys("%F4")
    oShell.AppActivate("Notepad");
    WScript.Sleep(500)
    oShell.SendKeys("^S");
    oShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
    WScript.Sleep(500);
    oShell.SendKeys("%F4")
    oShell.AppActivate("Powerpoint");
    WScript.Sleep(500)
    oShell.SendKeys("^S");
    oShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
    WScript.Sleep(500);
    oShell.SendKeys("%F4")
    oShell.AppActivate("Paint");
    WScript.Sleep(500)
    oShell.SendKeys("^S");
    oShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
    WScript.Sleep(500);
    oShell.SendKeys("%F4")
end
]
WScript.Echo( "Program Complete! Shutting Down..." )
'Script Ends Here
```

The story:
I had finished my assessment, an E-Zine, for grade eight at my high school, and I've been fiddling with code, I managed to make a visual basic script save all files, close it, then shutdown, the script only worked for notepad though.Since I've gotten home today, I've been expanding the script, and adding in a bit more, such as the classic 'Are you sure' prompt. But my computer is disagreeing...

I added that because it said:
'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>if ( sResult==6 ) {
   '...
end
]
```

is not VBScript. Proper syntax is

```
If sResult = 6 Then
    '...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a really silly mistake. I'm glad you answered.

Comment: var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") New Error...
'Object doesn't support this property or method' I'm good at batch, not vbs...

Comment: You cannot define and declare a variable on the same line. To simulate that you can do `Dim oShell: Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` The colon is a line separator.

Comment: @JoshuaHughes: One question per question please. If you have a new issue, post a new question with just the relevant bit of code please — not a dump of your entire program.